# How do I set up a virtual env for python in Chef recipe?

Tags: python, chef-infra

The goal is to clone a repo to the machine that is to run a Python script. And I need to install the requirements. However, I get this warning:

`WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv`

Below is my attempt to get rid of the warning, but I get the below error:

`had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /var/log/virtual-environment/bin/pip`

I am unsure how to modify the code to solve this issue?

```
# Cookbook: chefcookbookname
# Attribute file: attributes/default.rb

default['chefcookbookname']['venv_path'] = '/var/log/virtual-environment'
```

```
# Cookbook:: chefcookbookname
# Recipe:: default


package 'git'

package 'python3-pip'

package 'python3.10-venv'

directory '/var/log/tmp' do
  action :create
  recursive true
end

directory '/var/log/myrepo' do
  action :create
  recursive true
end

directory '/var/log/virtual-environment' do
  action :create
  recursive true
end

venv_path = node['chefcookbookname']['venv_path']

directory venv_path do
  action :create
end

execute 'create_virtualenv' do
  command "python3 -m venv #{venv_path}"
  not_if { ::File.exist?(venv_path) }
end

git 'clone_repository' do
  repository 'https://repo.git'
  reference 'main'
  destination '/var/log/myrepo'
  action :sync
end

execute 'move_requirements' do
  command "mv /var/log/myrepo/requirements.txt #{venv_path}"
  action :run
  only_if { ::File.exist?("/var/log/myrepo/requirements.txt") }
end

execute 'install_python_dependencies' do
  command "#{venv_path}/bin/pip install -r #{venv_path}/requirements.txt"
  only_if { ::File.exist?("#{venv_path}/requirements.txt") }
  environment(
    'VIRTUAL_ENV' => venv_path,
    'PATH' => "#{venv_path}/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
  )
end
```

Comment: Your requirement looks similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466953/activating-virtualenv-via-chef-recipe-and-install-python-library). See if it helps.

Comment: I'll take a look. I did try poise before making the  post and it didn't work. But I'll give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

The execute command can take a property called "user" which is the user name of the user identity with which to launch the new process.
For example, if your user is called `foo`

```
execute "python3 -m venv #{source_path}/virtualenv" do
  cwd '/path/where/to/create/venv'
  user 'foo'
  not_if { ::Dir.exist?("#{source_path}/virtualenv") }
  action :run
end
```

Comment: i will try this and let you know if it works.